# font not found with basic example

Tags: cjk, sharelatex

I'm using the exact same example of [using Chinese](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Chinese) here, but when try to compile it, it throws errors:

```
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "SimSun" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H &lt;return&gt;.
!...............................................  

l.3 \setCJKmainfont{SimSun.ttf}

? 
! Emergency stop.
!...............................................</p>
```

The code I used are:

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
 
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun.ttf}
\setCJKsansfont{SimHei.ttf}
\setCJKmonofont{SimFang.ttf}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\begin{abstract}
这是在文件的开头的介绍文字.本文的主要话题的简短说明.
\end{abstract}
\section{ 前言 }
在该第一部分中的一些额外的元素可以被添加。巴贝尔包将采取的翻译服务.
\section{关于数学部分}
在本节中的一些数学会使用数学模型含中文字符显示。
這是一個傳統的中國文字
\end{document}
```

I created a blank project on sharelatex and set the compiler to XeLatex.

Comment: Welcome! Please always post the code which produces the error in the form of a minimal example. (We don't need a whole document.) Is that font installed on your system? Probably you either need a full path or to use the name of the font. The page you linked to takes a long time to load and is then entirely blank except for the header of the page at the top, so I don't know what the setup there is at all.

Comment: If you are using Sharelatex, `your system` means `their system`. You probably need to upload the font to your working directory.

Comment: @cfr I don't get it, I do not have latex installed on my system. I think sharelatex is compiling the code on their servers, right?

Comment: That is why I said you probably need to upload the fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `fontspec` to select fonts, you can access any font installed on your system, provided it is in an appropriate format and reasonably sane.

The great thing about this is you can use fonts not packaged or installed for use with TeX.

The downside is that, of course, you have to actually have the fonts installed.

You are attempting to compile an example which relies on a system font which is not part of TeX distributions. To use this font, you need to get hold of a copy and put it somewhere XeTeX can find it.

If you are using an online compilation system, you can't install the font for the system. You will have to fall-back to the option of providing it with the path to the file.

This requires you to upload the font in question. The easiest option is to just upload it into the same directory as you `.tex` document. Then `<filename>.ttf` will work without worrying about the path.

There are some restrictions when using uninstalled fonts in this way, but for basic usage, it should work fine. (And the example is doing the same thing - loading by filename - so it must also be relying on this method. Hence, it should work fine.)

If you don't have the fonts required, you can upload other fonts and change the filenames. Just make sure they provide the coverage you need in terms of scripts etc.